# Overwriting method of built-in Number object fails when trying to execute test on it

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have written polyfill method for `Number.isInteger` function which looks like that:

```
export const isInteger = Number.isInteger
  || ((value) => typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value) && Math.floor(value) === value);
```

Everything is working fine here, but I wanted to test it with jest, but I'm unable to overwrite default `Number.isInteger` method inside this jest test case. Test looks like that:

```
it('should check if isInteger polyfill works correctly', function () {
    Number.isInteger = undefined;
    Number.prototype.isInteger = undefined;
    expect(isInteger(5)).toBe(true);
});
```

Test passes, but it is not executing the second part of statement inside `isInteger` constant. Question is how could I overwrite this method inside the test to force it to execute the polyfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.isInteger` is used at the time when the module is imported. It should be re-imported per test in order to use mocked `Number.isInteger`.

`Number.isInteger` should be restored to not affect anything outside this test.

`isInteger` is static method, `Number.prototype.isInteger` doesn't exist and doesn't need to be mocked.

It should be:

```
const isIntegerOriginal = Number.isInteger;

afterEach(() => {
  Number.isInteger = isIntegerOriginal;
});

it('should check if isInteger polyfill works correctly', function () {
    Number.isInteger = undefined;
    let isInteger;
    jest.isolateModules(() => {
      isInteger = require('...').isInteger;
    });
    expect(isInteger(5)).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, in this project I have very old version of jest, which is `21.0.2` and `isolateModules` simply doesn't exist. Is there a way to re-import it in some other way?

Comment: An alternative is `jest.resetModules(); let {isInteger} = require('...')`. It's better to move `jest.resetModules()` from a test to beforeEach, this will make it more predictable.